# Mostrar iconos en orden en Java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy haciendo un programa que muestra dos botones con dos colores distintos (en este caso Rojo y Azul) y segun el usuario presiona uno u otro lo plasma en un panel en forma de label que esta mas arriba, de manera que si el usuario presiona el boton Azul y luego el Rojo muestra: Azul --> Rojo. La idea es transformar ese texto a un icono individual en cada caso, que sea del color que se presiono. Por ejemplo si se presiona el Azul y luego el Rojo que se muestre un icono Azul y luego uno Rojo al lado del anterior en orden, del mismo modo que con los labels. Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo? La idea es que estos iconos sean ilimitados, ya que el usuario debe presionarlos cada vez que quiere!

Les dejo parte del codigo y una screenshot:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    if(contador<10){
            todo = jLabel1.getText();
            jLabel1.setText(todo+"--->"+"Azul");
            jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
            contador++;
            }else{
            jLabel1.setText("<html>"+todo+"<p><html>"); //Hace un salto de linea si se supera el valor de 10.
            contador = 0;
            }
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

            if(contador<10){
            todo = jLabel1.getText();
            jLabel1.setText(todo+"--->"+"Rojo");
            jPanel1.add(jLabel1);
            contador++;
            }else{
            jLabel1.setText("<html>"+todo+"<p><html>"); //Hace un salto de linea si se supera el valor de 10.
            contador = 0;
            }
}
```

Esto es lo que hace por ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dije la idea es que esos Label sean en realidad los colores ordenados.

Gracias de antemano :)

**P.D: Si hay una manera mas facil que hacerlo con iconos mejor! Lo importante es que muestre los colores en forma de imagen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mostrar iconos en orden en Java Swing

Para mostrar iconos, label, **componentes** en esa disposición, es ideal un **JPanel** con disposición `FlowLayout`, que los colocará uno al lado del otro.

Por defecto se colocarán empezando desde el centro. Para cambiar eso utilizaremos esta instrucción o campo de clase `FlowLayout.LEFT`, que en este caso empezarán desde la izquierda.

```
JPanel superior = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

---

> Según presiona el usuario, se irá dibujando un rectángulo o icono de **color** según **botón presionado**. La idea es que estos iconos sean ilimitados, ya que el usuario debe presionarlos cada vez que quiere!

Pues dentro del método `actionPerformed()` de cada botón, que es donde se generará el evento, crearemos un JLabel dinámicamente cada vez que se pulse cada uno de los botones estableciéndole un color de fondo.

```
//botón azul
btnBlue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
                lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,15));
                lbl.setOpaque(true);
                lbl.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                superior.add(lbl);
                superior.revalidate();

                System.out.println("btn azul");

            }
        });
```

***Creación del JLabel***

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
```

*Le damos o establecemos un tamaño preferido a nuestro label*

```
lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,15));
```

*Le damos una opacidad al componente o no podremos darle un color de fondo.*

```
lbl.setOpaque(true);
```

*Establecemos el color de fondo. En este caso **azul***

```
lbl.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

*Añadimos a nuestro panel.*

```
superior.add(lbl);
```

*Y hacemos que puede dibujarse dinámicamente con esta instrucción.*

```
superior.revalidate();
```

---

**Ejemplo completo..**

```
public class LabelConFondoColor extends JFrame {
    JPanel superior;

    public LabelConFondoColor() {
        miGUI();
    }

    private void miGUI() {
        superior = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));


        JPanel inferior = new JPanel();
        JButton btnBlue = new JButton("Azul");
        btnBlue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
                lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,15));
                lbl.setOpaque(true);
                lbl.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                superior.add(lbl);
                superior.revalidate();

                System.out.println("btn azul");

            }
        });
        JButton btnRed = new JButton("Rojo");
        btnRed.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
                lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,15));
                lbl.setOpaque(true);
                lbl.setBackground(Color.RED);
                superior.add(lbl);
                superior.revalidate();

                System.out.println("btn azul");
            }
        });

        inferior.add(btnBlue);
        inferior.add(btnRed);

        this.setBounds(300, 300, 570, 650);
        this.add("Center", superior);

        this.add("South", inferior);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabelConFondoColor app = new LabelConFondoColor();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Resultado..**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

---

**Actualizo.**

**Como poner Imagen a un JLabel y que se ajuste la imagen a el.**

**.** Tenemos nuestro JLabel..

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
```

**.** A parte del preferredSize, le vamos a dar un tamaño concreto

```
lbl.setSize(50, 15);
```

**.** Ahora creamos esa imagen

```
ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\miusuario\\Desktop\\coca-cola.png");
```

**.** Ahora esa imagen la **ajustamos** a la escala del `JLabel` y a su vez creamos un `Icon`.

```
Icon icono = new ImageIcon(imagen.getImage().getScaledInstance(lbl.getWidth(), lbl.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

**.** Y ya por último establecemos el Icono en el JLabel.

```
lbl.setIcon(icono);
```

---

**Te dejo el contenido de un `actionPerformed()`**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
                lbl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,15));
                lbl.setSize(50, 15);
                lbl.setOpaque(true);
                ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\dlolh\\Desktop\\coca-cola.png");
                Icon icono = new ImageIcon(imagen.getImage().getScaledInstance(lbl.getWidth(), lbl.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                lbl.setIcon(icono);

                superior.add(lbl);
                superior.revalidate();
            }
```

**Y el resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba bro! Pero antes, que pasa si quiero poner un icon en lugar de solo colores? (o sea una imagen por ejemplo), hay manera de hacerlo? Gracias y si pudiera te daría mas puntos ^^

Comment: Pues en vez de utilizar `setBackground`, utiliza `setIcon()`. Por ejemplo `lbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\miusuario\\Desktop\\coca-cola.png"));`

Comment: Hola @TaD, voy a actualizar la respuesta al final con esa información. También voy a poner como tenemos que **redimensionar** esa imagen para que se ajuste al `JLabel`. :D

Comment: Excelente explicación! Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Gracias a ti amigo :)