# Mostrar imágenes en orden en Android Studio usando una Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy haciendo una app que muestra varios botones y según el usuario presiona uno u otro lo plasma en una `LinearLayout` de manera dinamica en orden, asi si el usuario presiona el boton 1 y luego el 2 muestra: **1-->2** y así ilimitadamente. La idea es que cada vez que presione un botón muestre una imagen en la layout de la misma forma que los numeros. Mi pregunta es **como puedo hacer esto**. Hace un tiempo hice una **pregunta similar** pero para hacerlo en Java y obtuve una respuesta, la comparto aqui para que vean cual es mi idea: [Pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198915/mostrar-iconos-en-orden-en-java-swing)

**Foto de la idea en Java:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo con un `RecyclerView` con un `GridLayoutManager`.

La `Activity` principal.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_grid_view_sof);
    GridAdapter ga = new GridAdapter();
    RecyclerView rvGrid = findViewById(R.id.rv_grid);
    rvGrid.setAdapter(ga);
    Button btAzul = findViewById(R.id.bt_azul);
    Button btRojo = findViewById(R.id.bt_rojo);
    btAzul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ga.putImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }
    });
    btRojo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ga.putImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        }
    });
}
```

`Xml` de la `Acitivty`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="8"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_grid_sof"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_azul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Azul" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_rojo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rojo" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`Adapter` del `RecyclerView`

```
public class GridAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridAdapter.Holder> {
    private final List<Integer> listImages = new ArrayList<>(0);
    public void putImageResource(Integer res) {
        listImages.add(res);
        notifyItemInserted(listImages.size() - 1);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_grid_sof, parent, false));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listImages.size();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.image.setBackgroundResource(listImages.get(position));
    }
    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView image;
        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

`Xml` item del `adapter`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"/>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! De todas maneras como digo arriba me interesaría poner una imagen y no un color, como puedo hacer eso? Gracias!

Comment: Editado para una imagen de resource, si quiere un drawable o una url es cambiar la propiedad por lo que quieras.

Comment: Gracias, pude hacerlo andar. Pero antes una cosa mas, se puede redimensionar el RecyclerView en la pantalla? Y ademas, se puede dejar un espacio entre ambas imagenes? Por que aparecen muy apretadas y no se que parte del codigo debo modificar! Gracias por tu ayuda! 
P.D: Que dimensiones tienen que tener las imagenes para que entren bien? Por que aparecen algo mal jaja Ahora si no molesto mas :)

Comment: Las dimensiones están en el `xml` del `ImageView` `andod:layout_width="70dp" :layout_height="15dp"` pon el tamaño que te vaya bien, para el espacio entre ellas creo que con un margen en el mismo `layout` te funcionara.

Comment: Te hago una ultima pregunta (aunque ya te di los puntos :D) Como puedo borrar todas esas imagenes del layout con un simple boton? Algo asi como para que se limpie el layout! Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: En el `adapter` crea un método publico donde borres el contenido de la lista `listImages` y llamando al método `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Me podrías dar un pequeño ejemplo si no es mucha molestia? No logro darme cuenta como aplicar ese método. Mil gracias nuevamente

Comment: Hecho! @GMM muchas gracias!