# Eliminar elementos de una Linear Layout Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, linearlayout

Tengo una Linear Layout en Andorid Studio y quiero que al apretar un boton se borren todos los elementos que contiene. Este es el codigo que tengo, borra los elementos correctamente pero cuando en la misma app vuelvo a insertar otros elementos dinamicamente aparecen los que habia borrado anteriormente (no se si me explico). Les dejo el codigo:

```
borrarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            }
        });
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: pon el código en el que insertas los otros elementos

Comment: disculpa si digo algo raro es q hace rato no programo en android... creo q lo q tiens en el layout cuando actualizas lo guardas en un arreglo no.... x lo que veo lo eliminas del view pero no del arreglo...creo q es eso

Comment: @javimolla El código es el de esta pregunta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/208527/mostrar-imágenes-en-orden-en-android-studio-usando-una-linear-layout/209183?noredirect=1#comment390662_209183

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberías borrarlo de esta manera:

```
borrarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (layout.getChildCount() > 0) 
            layout.removeAllViews();
    }
});
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Hola, al colocar el codigo que me recomiendas solo se borran las vistas, pero al volver a generar elementos nuevos aparecen los viejos. Puede que me haya salteado algo en la explicacion, este es el codigo que uso: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/208527/mostrar-im%C3%A1genes-en-orden-en-android-studio-usando-una-linear-layout/209183?noredirect=1#comment390662_209183   Gracias!

Comment: Al parecer la respuesta estaba bien, solo tengo un problema en el hecho de que al apretar el boton se borra todo el contenido del layout y yo solo quiero que se borre lo de ese layout (por que dentro de el contengo otro distinto), voy a ver si lo puedo solucionar, asi todo gracias.

Comment: Si te sirvieron las respuestas por favor márcalas como útiles. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

> [removeAllViewsInLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViewsInLayout())  Llamado por una subclase ViewGroup para
>   eliminar las vistas secundarias de sí mismo, cuando primero debe
>   conocer su tamaño en la pantalla antes de poder calcular cuántas
>   vistas secundarias representará.

Si llamas unicamente removeAllViewsInLayout no funcionara, debes llamar tambien

> [requestLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout())  Llame a esto cuando haya cambiado algo que haya
>   invalidado el diseño de esta vista.

y

> [invalidate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#invalidate()) Forza a redibujar las vistas.

Realiza por lo tanto lo siguiente:

```
borrarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();

                layout.requestLayout();
                layout.invalidate();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hola, al colocar el codigo que me recomiendas no pasa nada, todo sigue tal cual, no se borra nada al apretar el boton. Puede que me haya salteado algo en la explicacion, este es el codigo que uso: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/208527/mostrar-im%C3%A1genes-en-orden-en-android-studio-usando-una-linear-layout/209183?noredirect=1#comment390662_209183   Gracias!

Comment: Al parecer la respuesta estaba bien, solo tengo un problema en el hecho de que al apretar el boton se borra todo el contenido del layout y yo solo quiero que se borre lo de ese layout (por que dentro de el contengo otro distinto), voy a ver si lo puedo solucionar, asi todo gracias.